# Refresh cache of Ranger file manager

Tags: ranger

How do I refresh ranger file manager? It automatically refreshes if a file is changed/edited/created/removed inside current directory, but I want to be able to force it to do so. How would I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See help `?`, `k`(eybindings):

```
Keybindings in `browser'
       R reload_cwd
```

Just press `R`.

---

There is actually bug where `reload_cwd` will not work when it just shows "empty" - it will be fixed with this PR: https://github.com/ranger/ranger/pull/2174

Comment: This removes my git info from statusline at the bottom of ranger. What does reload_cwd actually do? reload current working directory? Then why does it removes my git info?

Comment: @EnanAjmain IMO it does what you asked - you can find that with help/commands: `:reload_cwd` Reload the current working directory.